# Error in creating external content type list

Tags: 2010, bdc

When I want to create a SharePoint list from external content type on a client machine and when I click on "Select External Content Type", I am getting following error. The error does not happen, when I do the same operation on the server.

> string or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsPArserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehaviour runBehavior,SqlCommand cndHandler, SQlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsPArserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClient.SqlComand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(string methodName, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClient.SqlComand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, string methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClient.SqlComand.ExecuteNonQuery() at RedirectorModule.RedirectorModule.Application_BeginRequest(Object Source, EventArgs e)

Following is an extract from the logs

```
12/08/2015 18:50:04.56  w3wp.exe (xxxx) xxxxx   SharePoint Foundation   Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://zxxxxxx:9999/GUID/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:xxxxxx'    
12/08/2015 18:50:07.29  w3wp.exe (xxxx) xxxx    SharePoint Foundation   Topology    xxxx    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://xxxxxxxx:9999/GUID/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetThrottlingRules' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:xxxxxx' xxxxxxx
```

I checked the secure store which I am using and the credentials, Everything seems to be working. It seems like an issue with BDC service app on this farm or something to do with connectivity to SQL server.

Comment: Created a seperated External content type and when I tried to create a "external list" in the site and click on "Select External Content Type"  , I am getting the same error.